# what is the easiest way to find out whether one vector is rotation of another?

Tags: matlab

Let's assume we have  `a = [1 2 3 4]`, `b = [3 4 1 2]` and `c = [1 2 4 3]`. 
What is the easiest way to find out that `b` is the shift of `a` and `c` is not the shift of `a`?

And is there some functions for matrixes?

Comment: A circular convolution could be useful: A key step in my solution would probably be `cconv(a,b,length(a))`. http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/cconv.html

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `strfind`. If `a` is a rotation of `b`, then `a` should be found inside `[b b]`:

```
strfind([b b],a)
ans =
     3

>> strfind([c c],a)
ans =
     []
```

Comment: @user2055505: If you found the answer solved your problem, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate `a` `size(a)` times and check if the newly rotated vector is the same with `b`:

```
for i = 1:length(a),
    a = a([end 1:end-1])
    if(a == b)
        disp('true')
    end
end
```